# Set panel to fill but the height is scrollable in windows forms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Well, I have a panel that contain some forms. I set panel Dock to Fill because it will be good when window maximized. I set the minimum size of panel too because the contents/forms quite be long to bottom.

Sadly, the scroll bar not shown even I set AutoScroll to True and set AutoScrollMinSize. How to configure this properly?

Let's say I have window height size only 300px but the panel (in window) that contain my forms have height about 600px. I need to always show the scroll bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anchoring it to TOP for vertical scroll bar and Left for horizontal scroll bar? is it working?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks all, I finally figured out what's wrong. I don't need set the MinimumSize of panel

**Properties of Panel**

```
Dock: Fill
AutoScroll: true
AutoScrollMinSize: 600px (Height)
```

It will be automatically force the panel to follow AutoScrollMinSize instead MinimumSize or default Size.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any child anchord to the right of the panel, as showed in [MSDN documantation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll(v=vs.110).aspx):

> "There is currently a limitation in Windows Forms that prevents all
>   classes derived from ScrollableControl from acting properly when both
>   RightToLeft is enabled and AutoScroll is set to Yes. For example,
>   let's say that you place a control such as Panel—or a container class
>   derived from Panel (such as FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel)—on
>   your form. If you set AutoScroll on the container to Yes and then set
>   the Anchor property on one or more of the controls inside of the
>   container to Right, then no scrollbar ever appears. The class derived
>   from ScrollableControl acts as if AutoScroll were set to No.
>   Currently, the only workaround is to nest the ScrollableControl inside
>   another ScrollableControl. For instance, if you need TableLayoutPanel
>   to work in this situation, you can place it inside of a Panel control
>   and set AutoScroll on the Panel to Yes."